# Embed Unity3D Player inside Xamarin.Forms App

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to embed a Unity3D Player inside my Xamarin.Forms project? So I would like to create a little Unity project, add some Models / interactions / scenery, and finally embed it inside my App. I could imagine doing this with a WebView, but I think this will be relativly slow. Does anyone knows a good solution for this?